# How to add sub-sub-menus to a google spreadsheet using google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to add a second level sub-menu (sub-sub-menu) to a Google spreadsheet? I know how to add a menu with a sub-menu but what I need is to add one level more. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a sub-sub-menu now.
I believe you should be able to continue to nest multiple menus.

```
DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("TopMenu")
  .addItem('Top Item', 'topProgram')
  .addSeparator()
  .addSubMenu(DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('SubMenu')
              .addItem('Sub Item', 'subProgram')
              .addSubMenu(DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Sub Sub Menu')
                          .addItem('SubSub Item', 'subSubProgram')))

  .addToUi();
```

The idea above would that you create a menu and just added it as a "sub menu". The example below creates the same menu above, but more clearly broken out.

```
var subSubMenu = DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Sub Sub Menu')
                          .addItem('SubSub Item', 'subSubProgram');

var subMenu = DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Sub Menu')
                          .addItem('Sub Item', 'subProgram')
                          .addSubMenu(subSubMenu);

var topMenu = DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Top Menu')
                          .addItem('Top Item', 'topProgram')
                          .addSubMenu(subMenu);
topMenu.addToUi();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is not possible. You can take a look at [Issue 317](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=317&q=sub%20menu&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner), but it doesn't look like it has made any progress in the past 2 years, so don't get too excited. Anyways,  you can follow it and see if there are any updates.

Comment: I guess I will have to wait. Meanwhile I will try to separate the features in different spreadsheets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Second tier drop down menus are, IMO, not a great design pattern. You will get better use and it's possible to instead have each parent category as a separate menu with simple lists in each (unless of course you are looking for a gazillion commands).

I'm not looking to diminish your need, but not having it is a win for user experience.

Comment: The problem is that I already added 3 (each with 6 to 8 itmes) and I still need to add more. The space in the spreadsheet menu bar is limited, i.e., I can add as many as I want but with 3 or more it starts to look very crowded

Comment: sounds like quite a set of functions. could it be that one or 2 menu items could instead launch a UIApp as a modal dialog and launch the scripts from there?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
The key problem is to add menus in the right order to get rid of nasty message "Custom menus must contain at least one item"
[image]